# Значения в формате Json не отображается в ячейках TableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Делал по методу self-size table view cells raywenderlinch.Почему то данный массив в ViewDidLoad не передается, сделал "Брейк" и выдает результат  Value = 0.Скачал проект с сайта и посмотрел может что то пропустить смог.Сделал почти один в один.Почему у него идет передача данных , а у меня нет.Уже все delegate and datasourse  добавлял.

Event.swift

```
    import UIKit

    struct Event {
        let match : String
        let forecast : String
        let data : String
        let image : UIImage
        var sports : [Sport]

        init (match : String, forecast : String, data: String, image : UIImage, sports : [Sport]) {

        self.match = match
        self.forecast = forecast
        self.data = data
        self.image = image
        self.sports = sports


      }

        static func eventsFromBundle ()-> [Event] {

            var events = [Event] ()


            guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "events", withExtension: "json") else {
                return events
            }
                do {
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                    guard let rootObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String : Any]  else {

                        return events
                    }

                    guard let eventObjects = rootObject["events"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
                        return events
                    }
                    for eventObject in eventObjects {
                        if let match = eventObject["match"] as? String,
                            let forecast = eventObject["forecast"]  as? String,
                            let data = eventObject["data"] as? String,
                            let imageName = eventObject["image"] as? String,
                            let image = UIImage(named: imageName),
                            let sportsObject = eventObject["sports"] as? [[String : String]]{
                            var sports = [Sport]()
                            for sportObject in sportsObject {
                              if let  nameTitle = sportObject["name"] ,
                                    let titleName = sportObject["image"],
                                    let titleImage = UIImage(named: titleName + ".jpg"),
                                    let prognozLabel = sportObject["prognoz"],
                                    let obzor = sportObject["obzor"] {
                                sports.append(Sport(name: nameTitle, prognoz: prognozLabel, image: titleImage, obzor: obzor, isExpanded: false))

                                }
                            }

                            let event = Event(match: match, forecast: forecast, data: data, image: image, sports: sports)
                            events.append(event)

                        }
                    }


                } catch {
                    return events
            }

            return events
        }

    }
```

import UIKit

```
    class SportViewController: BaseViewController {

        var events = Event.eventsFromBundle ()


        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            addSlideMenuButton()
            tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100


        }

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIContentSizeCategoryDidChange, object: .none, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] _ in
               self?.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }


            override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? SportDetailViewController,
                let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                destination.selectedEvent = events[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }



    extension SportViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return events.count
     }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellMatch", for: indexPath) as! SportTableViewCell

        let event = events[indexPath.row]
        cell.matchLabel.text = event.match
        cell.imageMatch.image = event.image
        cell.forecastLabel.text = event.forecast
        cell.dataLabel.text = event.data

        cell.matchLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)
        cell.forecastLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .callout)
        return cell

        }
    }


 import UIKit

    class SportDetailViewController: UIViewController {

        var selectedEvent : Event!



        let obzorText = "Select for more info >"

        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            title = selectedEvent.match
            tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300



            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
               }
            override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewDidAppear(animated)


                }

        }



     extension SportDetailViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
         {
            return selectedEvent.sports.count

        }



     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell : SportDetailTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellMatch", for: indexPath) as! SportDetailTableViewCell

                let sport = selectedEvent.sports[indexPath.row]


                cell.nameTitle.text = sport.name
                cell.titleImage.image = sport.image
                cell.prognozLabel.text = sport.prognoz
                cell.selectionStyle = .none
                cell.nameTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

                cell.obzorText.text = sport.isExpanded ? sport.obzor : obzorText
                cell.obzorText.textAlignment = sport.isExpanded ? .left : .center

                return cell
    }
       }



     extension SportDetailViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? SportDetailTableViewCell else { return }

            var sport = selectedEvent.sports[indexPath.row]

            sport.isExpanded = !sport.isExpanded
            selectedEvent.sports[indexPath.row] = sport

            cell.obzorText.text = sport.isExpanded ? sport.obzor : obzorText
            cell.obzorText.textAlignment = sport.isExpanded ? .left : .center


            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()

            tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в конце метода viewDidLoad вызов
tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Дмитрий, я уже пробывал.Может есть еще какие варианты?

Comment: var events = Event.eventsFromBundle () инициализируется задолго до viewDidLoad если он у вас пустой то возможно срабатывает один из guard. Поставьте брейк поинт на 
var events = [Event] () и посмотрите где заканчивается инициализиация массива. возможно вы не добавили в проект файл с JSON который пытаетесь открыть через Bundle.main.url

Comment: Я проверил  по вашему методу, знаете мне выдает events = 0 передача.Но файл у меня json в проекте есть.И я написал верно все данные в скрипте , если я не правильно вел код, у меня были пустые ячейки.Но сейчас   почему то пол проекта отображается.Я не думаю что в другой части проекта конечно не правильно указал.Я понял что если правильно все вводишь передает все, если хоть скобку одну не указал, то данные твои отображаться не будут.

Comment: очень похоже что не парсится JSON

если файл у вас есть и вы попадаете в тело оператора do
то 

`let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)`

это данные из файла - не должны быть nil
дальше

 `guard let eventObjects = rootObject["events"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
                        return events
                    }`

видимо данные не являются массивом из дикшенри [[String: AnyObject]]

и кстати если вы в Swift 3 поменяйте AnyObject на Any

Comment: так я вот по этому проекту делал свое https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells.Почему у него тогда идет.

Comment: Попробовал не помогло (((

Comment: ну так если массив модели пустой - то и не поможет
должен инициализироваться массив а судя по описанию JSON не парситься

Comment: не правильно Json файл написал?

Comment: думаю да - его можно валидировать например на каком нибудь онлайн верификаторе